# How to avoid rolling execution of a job(pentaho data integration)

Tags: mysql, csv, pentaho, pdi, pentaho-ctools

I have got a job which run several transformations. some transformations contain the mysqlbulkloader. however my question is to understand why does i have got the feeling the job runs twice knowing that my execution results return each time this kind of errors.

```
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - Evaluate files metrics - File [${ADV_DWH_SERVER_DIRECTORY}/cm/tmp/stg_orbit_gb_user.txt] deleted!
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Starting entry [Success]
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Success] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Delete tmp gb_user file ] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_gb_user] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Delete tmp tl_journal file] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_tl_journal] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Delete tmp ln_history file] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_reversal_change_ln_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_ln_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Delete tmp gl_history file] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_reversal_change_gl_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_gl_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Delete tmp dp_history file] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_reversal_change_dp_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:32 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history] (result=[true])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Starting entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - Loading transformation from repository [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history] in directory [/STG]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - Dispatching started for transformation [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/advans/bi/cm/tmp/stg_orbit_dp_history.txt (No such file or directory)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - /var/advans/bi/cm/tmp/stg_orbit_dp_history.txt (No such file or directory)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - 
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.openNextFile(CsvInput.java:397)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.processRow(CsvInput.java:130)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/advans/bi/cm/tmp/stg_orbit_dp_history.txt (No such file or directory)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.openNextFile(CsvInput.java:341)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 -    ... 3 more
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - CSV file input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Get System Info.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=0)
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Starting entry [Abort job]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Abort job - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Aborting job.
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [Abort job] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_generic_dp_history] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables - Starting entry [Abort job]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Abort job - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Aborting job.
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables - Finished job entry [Abort job] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables - Finished job entry [J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_fact] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables - Finished job entry [J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_table_dim] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_def_dim] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Starting entry [Move zip from reception dir to error dir]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Starting entry [Delete tmp files 2]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Starting entry [Delete sentinel files 2]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Starting entry [Abort job]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Abort job - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Aborting job.
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [Abort job] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [Delete sentinel files 2] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [Delete tmp files 2] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [Move zip from reception dir to error dir] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [J_STG_ORBIT_deserialize_one_zip_all_tables] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_check_orbit_date] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [Unzip from file] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_get_filenames_from_result] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Starting entry [Abort job]
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Abort job - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Aborting job.
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Finished job entry [Abort job] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Finished job entry [J_STG_ORBIT_process_all_zips] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Finished job entry [Evaluate files metrics] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Finished job entry [T_STG_ORBIT_check_sentinel_exists] (result=[false])
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - /STG/J_STG_load - Job execution finished
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Kitchen - Finished!
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Finished with errors
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Kitchen - Start=2015/06/22 13:07:53.978, Stop=2015/06/22 15:27:33.688
2015/06/22 15:27:33 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 2 hours, 19 minutes and 39 seconds (8379 seconds total).
```

Comment: Could you please format your code correctly? Click "Edit" below the post, then select your code and hit Ctrl+K to add code formatting.

Comment: 'how about now', thanks shotgun

Comment: Is this Pentaho CE or EE? Pentaho EE has the capability for "Job Checkpoints", the doc is here: http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0P0/0U0/0A0/020

Comment: it is EE and more over i am using the mysqlload bulker which dont allow me to run from window OS

Comment: Another question matb, does the put file ftp works perfectly?

Comment: Could it be that your job has "Copy previous results to parameters?" along with "Execute for every input row?" checked in the job settings?

Comment: Where exactly in the job setting please

Comment: Sorry mate, comment went off my radar, there you go: http://i.imgur.com/RdiSYIm.png?1

Comment: So if i got you right i should remove that tick box and this would resolve the all issue......